# Puppeteer - Passing a variable to page.evaluate()

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape a bunch of tables on a page with Puppeteer but the amount of tables varies each time and therefore i need to pass a variable into the page.evaluate() function.

I have an array containing the variables i need to use but lets say i wanna check the second table manually using a variable, here's how i approached the problem initially:

```
const x = 2
let value = await page.evaluate(() =>
document.querySelector("#pageBody > div:nth-child(" + x + ") > table > tr > td").innerText
);
console.log(value);

//Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

After some research,from what i understand, the correct way of passing a variable in there is:

```
const x = 2;
let value = await page.evaluate((x) => { 
document.querySelector("#pageBody > div:nth-child(" + x + ") > table > tr > td").innerText 
}, x);
console.log(value);

//value = undefined
```

But since im not getting the results i want, there's something im doing wrong or not understanding properly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. Of course 5 minutes after posting to SO following hours of frustration, but here goes:

```
const x = 2;
let value = await page.evaluate((x) => { 
return Promise.resolve(document.querySelector("#pageBody > div:nth-child(" + x + ") > table > tr > td").innerText) 
}, x);
console.log(value);
```

Comment: You don't need Promise.resolve for that FTR, you just needed the `return`

Comment: I did do a try with that earlier but i didnt get it to work. Maybe messed something else up in those tries. Could my way of doing it with ```Promise.resolve()``` cause any problems? (fairly new to async js)

Answer (score 1):

I'll just add this to  settle some confusion, if you do it in a one line arrow function you don't need the return:

```
const css = "#pageBody > div:nth-child(" + x + ") > table > tr > td"
let value = await page.evaluate((css) => document.querySelector(css).innerText), css);
```

Comment: Part from that you had one too many closing brackets that worked well aswell. Correct syntax would be:

 ```let value = await page.evaluate((css) => document.querySelector(css).innerText, css);```